# How to solve React issue A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code, but when I run it I get a React warning in console

```
A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa)
```

The component I am using is controlled I think, why do I get this warning?

```
import React from "react";

class Translator extends React.Component {
  state = {
    textInput: "",
  };

  handleTextInputChange(value) {
    this.setState({ textInput: value });
  }

  render() {
    const translation = this.props.translations.get(this.state.textInput);
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="controls">
          <div className="input-container">
            <span>input:</span>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="text-input"
              data-testid="text-input"
              value={this.state.textInput}
              onChange={(e) => this.handleTextInputChange(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="input-container">
            <span>output:</span>
            <input
              ref={this.inputElm}
              type="text"
              className="text-output"
              data-testid="text-output"
              readOnly
              value={translation}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Translator;
```

Comment: What is the initial value of `translation` when `this.state.textInput === ""`, I assume it is `undefined`. If you have the value of an input as `undefined` it is treated the same as not having defined at all, then when it eventually gets a value it's swapping from uncontrolled to controlled. Make the value of your translation function return an empty string when there is no input or change value on the second input to `translation ?? ''`

Comment: thanks please add it as answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0):

When the value assigned to an `input` is `undefined` it is treated as not being set at all. This means that the component will be treated as uncontrolled.

When the value is updated to be anything other than `undefined` the input will then become controlled which generates the warning that is being displayed.

In the example code I assume this is caused by the function `this.props.translations.get(this.state.textInput)` returning `undefined` when `this.state.textInput` is an empty string.

Two possible ways to fix this would be:

1. Make `this.props.translations.get` return an empty string if there is no translation instead of `undefined` (this requires anyone using the component to understand this limitation).
2. Change the value of the second input to provide an empty string when `translation` is `undefined`, i.e. `value={translation ?? ''}`.